# How to set USB Audio as default at boot Linux Mint17

Tags: linux, firefox, usb, audio

Lenovo G580 running Linux Mint 17 and using ALSA for sound.
Using config files I can play sound through USB port from VLC and other apps. but cannot get sound from Firefox, Chrome or any other browser (OK through default HDA_Intel on inbuilt speakers). I have trawled every help site and tried all suggestions with no success.  I read somewhere (but cannot find it again) that the problem is basically that Firefox needs the USB sound device to be device zero and the only solution is to edit grub.cfg to accomplish that at startup.  I am new to Linux and do not know what command to add to grub.cfg.  Advice please.
I have read and tried all suggested solutions for lack of usb sound at superuser.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Linux Mint 17, unless you uninstalled it or configured in order to bypass it, you are probably using the sound server PulseAudio. If this is the case, you can install PulseAudio Volume Control via `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`. Once installed, you should be able to use it to choose which output to use for each application using the **Playback** tab and to choose a default one in the **Output Devices** tab.

Once the application is emitting sound, it should appear in the **Playback** tab and you should be able to change its output device using this button:

[image]

Comment: That worked thank you. I had previously removed Pulse-Audio because, following a post on another site, I thought it was the problem.  Re-installed at your suggestion and now all is fine.  So far as I can tell the only change I have made in the meantime is to blacklist the inbuilt soundcard.